# How to dispatch a different event from inside an event handler?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have an event listener for a custom event type. This custom event overrides the clone method as required.

In this event listener I want to dispatch an instance of a different type of event... a different custom event instance altogether. It also overrides the clone method as required.

The problem is I'm getting a type coercion error: `TypeError: Error #1034: Type Coercion failed: ...`

I do not know what is trying to do the casting. My code is:

```
/* elsewhere in a method */
addEventListener(GestureEvent.GESTURE_SCALE, handlePinched);

/* the event handler */
private function handlePinched(e:GestureEvent):void
{
    dispatchEvent(new BezelEvent( BezelEvent.PINCH, e ));
}
```

`BezelEvent.PINCH` evaluates to `"__bezel_event_pinch"` which is a unique string that isn't colliding with other events.

And yet, I'm getting this type coercion... Yes, it's in a "dispatchEvent loop" handling an event, but dispatching a different event based on some event seems like a SUPER common and trivial scenario. Can anyone figure out why it's trying to convert my new BezelEvent instance to a GestureEvent instance??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly silly silly...

The answer: Make sure your eventHandlers listening for the new event are expecting the right event type.

My handler for the BezelEvent event was defined as expecting a GestureEvent. Changing the handler to expect BezelEvent fixed the problem.

Let me daftness save you some time.

*sigh*